# "Search Setting" missing from 'Search And MetaData' section on configuration page

Tags: search, domain-access

I have a problem. I have a project that uses Domain Access.
I recently installed the "Search API" module and attempted to set up an indexing configuration.  That all went well, but when I tried to index the items I tried going to Drupal 'configuration' page, and under "Search And MetaData" section, there should be a link called "Search Settings", but there is not.

In a different project that did not use Domain Access I set this up and it works fine. Here is an example of the project that has search api set up properly and "Search Settings" shows up under "Search and Metadata"

[image]

I can click on "Search Settings" and it takes me to the "Search Settings" page where I can index my nodes, as well as a few other configuration options.

For my new project that uses Domain Access the "Search Settings" section is missing from "Search and Metadata", behold:

[image]

I initially thought it might be a permissions problem, and went to permissions section and the both have 'administrator' set under permissions for "administer search api".

Does anyone have any idea why my new project that uses Domain Access might be missing this page?  I tried going to the "Search Settings" page by manually typing the url into my browser, but it said "Access Denied". (I also have Access Denied backtrace set up and no reports were being generated after it gave me the access denied.

The only reason I mention that my new site uses Domain Access is because that is the only major difference between the 2 projects that I can see.

I would really love some help with this, and would consider it my Xmas present.  :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer out.
I thought that the "Search Setting" configuration section was created for the "Search API" module, but it is actually for the core "Search" module.
Re-enabling the core "Search" module caused the "Search Setting" configuration section to reappear.